# Why won't my AMD video driver update to the latest version?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

This web site says the latest version is 15.7.1

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%208.1%20-%2064

> For users looking for a WHQL certified driver, the AMD Catalyst™ 15.7.1 driver will continue to be available for users running Windows® 10, Windows® 8.1, and Windows® 7.

I downloaded `amd-catalyst-15.7.1-with-dotnet45-win8.1-64bit.exe` and installed it and rebooted, but the version in Windows shows 15.2.

[image: amd radeon hd 7500 series driver]

Why won't it update to 15.7?

Windows 8.1, AMD Radeon HD 7570 1GB GDDR5

Comment: Isn't the one already installed more recent?  It was released a few days later and version 15.200.1062.1004 appears higher than 15.7.1.

Comment: The latest driver available for that card appears to be the Crimson Edition 16.2.1 Beta at the bottom of this page http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows+8.1+-+64   Also, The 15.7 version refers to the catalyst software version, not the driver version. Catalyst 15.7.1 contains the driver version you have, 15.200.1062.1004